# How can my script determine if installation of a certain Windows Installer update (MSP) succeeded or failed?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-installer

I've written a PowerShell script (see below) to install a very large number of MSP updates (files with `.msp` extensions, deployed via Windows Installer) one after the other. Now, I'd like this script to also tell me when the installation of an MSP update failed.

**Things that I have tried: Querying the error code.** There are two approaches:

- One is to get the error code using $LASTEXITCODE after running `MSIEXEC.EXE` directly. It is tedious.
- The other involved adding `-PassThru` switch to `Start-Process`, storing its result into an object, say `$a` and read the error code using `$a.ExitCode`. Like this:

  ```
  $a=Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/p `"$MspRelPath`" /log `"$LogRelPath`" /passive /norestart" -Wait -PassThru
  Write-Host $a.ExitCode
  ```

Neither prove useful. It seems `msiexec.exe` always returns zero as the exit code.

---

In case anyone is interested, here is the script:

```cs
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][Switch]$BypassAdminPrompt
)
Try 
{
  Clear-Host

  # Get script name
  $ScriptFileObject=(Get-Item $PSCommandPath)
  $ScriptName=$ScriptFileObject.Name
  $ScriptPath=$ScriptFileObject.DirectoryName

  # Load Windows Forms and initialize visual styles
  [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
  [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

  # Is the script holding administrative privileges?
  $wid=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
  $prp=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($wid)
  $adm=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
  $IsAdmin=$prp.IsInRole($adm)
  if ($IsAdmin -eq $false) {
    if (!$BypassAdminPrompt) {
      Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy $env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference -File `"$PSCommandPath`" -BypassAdminPrompt" -Verb RunAs
    } else {
      $result=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This script requires administrative privileges, which are absent.", $ScriptName, "OK", "Error");
    }
    break;
  }

  # Install...
  Set-Location $ScriptPath
  $MSP_list = Get-ChildItem *.msp -Recurse
  if ($MSP_list -eq $null) {
    $result=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Nothing found to install.`rSearch path was "+$ScriptPath, $ScriptName, "OK", "Error");
  }
  else
  {
    $MSP_list | ForEach-Object {
      # Ordinarily, I'd pass the path in the form of ".\foldername\filename.msp" but Windows Installer does not accept that.
      # It must be in "foldername\filename.msp" form.
      $MspRelPath = $_.FullName.Substring($ScriptPath.Length+1)
      $LogRelPath = $MspRelPath+".log"
      Write-Host $MspRelPath
      Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/p `"$MspRelPath`" /log `"$LogRelPath`" /passive /norestart" -Wait
    }
    Remove-Variable MspRelPath
    Remove-Variable LogRelPath
    Pause
  }
  Remove-Variable MSP_list
}
Catch
{
  $result=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error!`r`r"+$Error[0], $ScriptName, "OK", "Error");
  break;
}
```

Comment: You can easily find installed updates in Control panel/Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

either check Windows Events for MSIExec events or get the log output contents once done and check for failure indications.

I have a script that installs an MSI remotely using MSIExec, waits for MSIExec to close out (or the process/service to start)... if nothing happens after a typical install time, I check the log path included in the MSIExec call and check for failure or success messages

Comment: I don't find no Windows Event. I can ask `msiexec` to generate a log, but how do I interpret success or failure from that log programmatically? Hell, how do I interpret anything from that log? I am sure Microsoft intended this log to torment admins, not help them.